# affiliated operator lies in the von neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra.
Suppose $h$ is a positive self-adjoint operator which is affiliated to the center of $M$ . If $p$ is the spectral projection of $h$， we know that $p$ belongs to the center of $M$.

My question : can we conclude that $hp\in M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Think of $p=1$. If, on the other hand, $p$ is the spectral projection corresponding to a bounded Borel set (that is, $p=1_{K}(h)$ for some Borel $K\subset\mathbb C$) then $hp\in M$, as by the Spectral Theorem it is a limit of linear combinations of projections in $M$.

Comment: If $K$ is not bounded, $hp$ will not be bounded either.